# Single sign on without ADFS

Tags: asp.net, iis, single-sign-on

The application is hosted on IIS 7 and is asp.net appliaction, the users need to be authenticated by identity provider which is Active Directory. for that i need to generate relying party trust  to be added to ADFS identity provider. the application is hosted on web server which is not connected to a domain so i can not install ADFS on web server to generate relying party trust and implement automatic or single sign on and generate relying party trust metadata.
How do i implement single or automatic sign in for users-
How do i generate relying party trust from IIS without Active directory Federation service-

Answer (score 0):

Your IIS Server does not need to be on a domain joined machine. You can deploy AD FS on another domain joined machine and then add a relying party for that application. As far as automatic sign in is concerned, you can configure Windows Authentication for AD FS, which will enable you to automatically sign in without the need to enter your credentials.